# MySQL Query max issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that that works fine as long as there exists values in it after the `WHERE` condition is called. However, in some cases the query is empty because no values `= '$project_id'`.  In this scenario it enters a blank field to the table.  I would like to enter 1 by default if no values meet the `WHERE` condition.

Here is my query

```
$query = 
"INSERT INTO tapp_contact_list 
  (id, location) 
SELECT (MAX(id)+1), '$location' 
FROM tapp_contact_list
WHERE meeting_project_id = '$project_id'
";
```

Any help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: So you want to query one special row, but fetch/insert the one "above" as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$query = 
"INSERT INTO tapp_contact_list 
  (id, location) 
SELECT COALESCE( (MAX(id)+1), 1 ) , '$location' 
FROM tapp_contact_list
WHERE meeting_project_id = '$project_id'
";
```

For more details check this function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce